# Python - SMTP Monitoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

We are using Elasticemail for our SMTP server and running in issues where our server would fail to connect to the SMTP server for various reasons. Currently, we only find out about the issue when a user complains.

We want to monitor the connection to the server on a regular interval and notify Admin if there is a connection failure.

Is there any way to test the connection to the server without sending an actual email using Python3?

Comment: Just connect, then issue a `QUIT`?

Comment: As far as I can tell https://elasticemail.com/ uses their own HTTP-based API, not SMTP at all.